# Ubuntu doesn't detect an external monitor

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have two monitors. The first one works fine with both my windows and my Ubuntu 15.10 machines. The second one works with my windows machine, but not with my Ubuntu machine. It is outputing a DVI signal through a DVI-HDMI adapter cable to the hdmi port of the laptop. I am using nvidia proprietary drivers. When I run xrandr it says that HDMI-1-0 is disconnected, even though the cable is connected. I've tried it both when running the NVIDIA card, and the intel card, doesn't work. I've tried manually adding a new mode with xrandr for the HDMI output, and it does appear, but when I then try to use `xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP-1-0`, but the laptop screen just flickers and goes back to normal. I've tried several different nvidia drivers (now using 361), I've also tried the noveau drivers as well, same story. I know the cable and the monitor work fine, because they do on the windows machine, and I know that the port on the Ubuntu machine works fine, because it does with a different monitor. Any ideas?

Xorg log - http://paste.ubuntu.com/15803798/